# Show Print and Save Image option using ActionSheetIOS.showShareActionSheetWithOptions

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement ActionSheetIOS.showShareActionSheetWithOptions, I am passing the correct url which might be a link to an image or a file(pdf/msword).

I want to provide an option to Print the file or Save Image file when the user clicks on the Share button. But I only see the following options
"Add to reading list", "Copy" and more

Here's my code:

```
ActionSheetIOS.showShareActionSheetWithOptions({
  url: route.passProps.url,
},
(error) => alert(error),
(success, method) => { }
);
```

I have verified that the url is correct.
When visiting a url, Safari does provide you an option to Print/Save, so I know its possible, but I don't know how.